# DataTables - Disable Smart Search

Tags: r

I searched the documentation, but when applying it to my api it didn't work... I need to disable DataTables smart search. Insert "smart": false at startup as below:

```
var table = $('table#tbitens').DataTable({
    "ajax" : "/api/v1/get/itens/dtItem?baixado=" + baixado,
    "deferRender": true,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "destroy": false,
    "scrollX": "100%",
    "scrollY": "50vh",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "stateSave": true,
    select: {
        style: 'single'
    },
    "search": {
        "smart": false
    },
```

[Imagem do sistema de busca](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKLql.png)

In the search button I tried these two ways, the one commented on and the one on the top line, but without success. If anyone can help, I appreciate it, I'm new in the area and I'm still in the learning process. Trying to solve this task since Monday.

```
//Botão pesquisar
            $('#btnPesquisarItem').on('click', function(){
                var otable = $('#tbitens').DataTable();
                var collection = $("input.column_filter");
                collection.each(function() {
                    if ($(this).val().trim() != ''){
                        otable.columns($(this).parents('tr').attr('data-column')).search("^" + $(this).val() + "$", true, false, true).draw();
                            // original: otable.columns($(this).parents('tr').attr('data-column')).search($(this).val().trim());
                    }
                });
```

HTML

```
    <div class="tab-content" id="tabConteudo">
      <!-- FILTROS -->
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pesquisar" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pesquisar-tab">
        <div class="table-responsive p-2">
            <div class="row">
            <form id="formitens" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" style="margin: 10px">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <table style="width: 67%; margin: 0 auto 2em auto;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr id="filter_col0" data-column="1">
                                <td>Empresa</td>
                                <td align="center"><input type="text" class="column_filter" id="col1_filter"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="filter_col1" data-column="2">
                                <td>Filial</td>
                                <td align="center"><input type="text" class="column_filter" id="col2_filter"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="filter_col2" data-column="3">
                                <td>Item</td>
                                <td align="center"><input type="text" class="column_filter" id="col3_filter"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="filter_col3" data-column="4">
                                <td>Agregado</td>
                                <td align="center"><input type="text" class="column_filter" id="col4_filter"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="filter_col4" data-column="5">
                                <td>Chapa</td>
                                <td align="center"><input type="text" class="column_filter" id="col5_filter"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="filter_col5" data-column="6">
                                <td>Descrição</td>
                                <td align="center"><input type="text" class="column_filter" id="col6_filter"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="filter_col6" data-column="7">
                                <td>Conta</td>
                                <td align="center"><input type="text" class="column_filter" id="col7_filter"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="filter_col7" data-column="8">
                                <td>Classe</td>
                                <td align="center"><input type="text" class="column_filter" id="col8_filter"></td>
                            </tr>
                             <tr id="filter_col8" data-column="9">
                                <td>Centro</td>
                                <td align="center"><input type="text" class="column_filter" id="col9_filter"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
        
                </div>
                </form>
                
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <button type="submit" id="btnPesquisarItem" class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Pesquisar
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" id="btnLimparPesquisa" class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Limpar pesquisa
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      
      
      
      
      
      <!-- ITENS -->
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="itens" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="itens-tab">
        
        <div class="table-responsive p-2">
            <div class="panel-header p-1">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <a class="tip btn btn-sm btn-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Insere um novo item" th:href="@{/itens/add/}"
                            sec:authorize="hasAnyAuthority('Administrador', 'Aquisições')">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4" sec:authorize="hasAnyAuthority('Administrador', 'Movimentações')">
                        <select id="movimentacoes" autofocus="autofocus">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione um item para movimentar</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="form-group form-check">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="verBaixados">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Exibir Itens Baixados</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table id="tbitens" class="table table-sm table-hover table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Empresa</th>
                        <th>Filial</th>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Agregado</th>
                        <th>Chapa</th>
                        <th>Descrição</th>
                        <th>Conta</th>
                        <th>Classe</th>
                        <th>Centro</th>
                         
                        <th:block th:each="area : ${areasConts}">
                            
                            <th th:text="#{general.cost} + ' ' + ${area.descricao}">Custo</th>
                            <th th:text="#{general.depreciation} + ' ' + ${area.descricao}">Depreciação</th>
                        
                        </th:block>
                        
                        <th></th>
                         
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
                
                
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: SO is an **English-only** site - please respect the rules of the site, and translate your question (including title!) into English, or else post it on [pt.so]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not in English

Comment: Why is this tagged R? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Camille, it's not working... I tried to disable smart search, but it didn't work and I don't know why they closed my doubt

Comment: @DanielaArantes Your question was closed because it was not translated to English language. I voted to re-open now and reverted my downvote.